# Why does Azure Elastic Scale does not support string datatype as sharding keys?

Tags: .net, azure, azure-sql-database

From Microsoft Azure documentation:

> Elastic Scale support the following .Net framework types as sharding
>   keys:
>
> - integer
> - long
> - guid
> - byte[]
> - datetime
> - timespan
> - datetimeoffset

Why isn't string supported?

Comment: Probably because all of those types are a handful of bytes, whereas string could be millions of bytes.

Comment: We are trying to find Microsoft Engineers that can help us answer this question. Thank you for your patience.

Answer (score 2):

As the poster above suggests, unconstrained strings are an inefficient way to index content in a database (the shard map is stored in a SQL Database).  Under the hood, the elastic database client library (EDCL) normalizes all the supported types to byte[] and uses that in the shard map in the database. You can effectively use a string as a key if you convert it to one of the supported types.

You can see this done in the [WingtipSaaS sample application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-wtp-overview), which uses the name of a venue as a key.  We chose to convert the name to an integer key (it's easier to trace integer values in the code for demo and exploration purposes), but could have stopped at the byte[].  The conversion is done using an MD5 hash of a UTF8 encoding of the name. The PowerShell code below is from the Get-TenantKey function, used by several management scripts.  You can find the C# equivalent in the client app.  The sample is here:(https://github.com/Microsoft/WingtipSaaS).  The function below is in the ...\Learning Modules\Common\CatalogAndDatabaseManagement.psm module.

```
$normalizedTenantName = $TenantName.Replace(' ', '').ToLower()


# Produce utf8 encoding of tenant name 

$utf8 = New-Object System.Text.UTF8Encoding

$tenantNameBytes = $utf8.GetBytes($normalizedTenantName)


# Produce the md5 hash which reduces the size

$md5 = new-object -TypeName System.Security.Cryptography.MD5CryptoServiceProvider

$tenantHashBytes = $md5.ComputeHash($tenantNameBytes)

# Convert to integer for use as the key in the catalog 

$tenantKey = [bitconverter]::ToInt32($tenantHashBytes,0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Good day,

These are .Net framework types that can serve as **sharding keys**
How can you use free text as sharding key ( I am not saying you can't but saying it is not the same like using INT for example and it can be much more complex in general case)?

A String is supported for use with Elastic Scale but it cannot serve as unique key for sharding. A String can be mapped to NVARCHAR(MAX) for example which is not supported as primary key for the same reasons. If you try to create it you will get the error:

> Column... is of a type that is invalid for use as a key column in an index.

The sharding keys used for "decision" where the value is stored (in which shared database). for example you can configure range shard map and choose that all values between 1 to 100 will stored in database A and all values from 100 to 200 will be stored in database B and so on. Free string does not fit this nature.

Theoretically, you can say that you want to use range on string but it does not make sense in Big Data systems and the Elastic Scale is a solution for Big Data system based on Azure SQL Databases.

I hope this clarify the issue :-)